# Тест длится по времени больше, чем задано в конфигурационном файле

Tags: яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

### Параметры Yandex-Tank

### Файл load.ini

```
[loadosophia]
token=NameToken
project=NameProject
test_title=Random
[phantom]
address = 10.79.8.250
port = 8088
rps_schedule=const(80,60)
timeout=10s
instances=20
writelog = 0
; Headers and URIs for GET requests
header_http = 1.0
ammofile=./app.txt
ammo_type=uri
; headers = [Connection: close]
ssl = 0
```

---

### Пример файла app.txt

```
/app?example1&app=1
/app?example2&app=1
/app?example3&app=1
/app?example4&app=1
```

---

### Описание проблемы

В настоящее время тест идет заданное время и ещё какой-то срок. Этот "остаток" чаще всего превышает заданное время тестирования в несколько раз. Возможно, невнимательно читаю документацию, но такого там не видела. Хочу понять, почему так происходит.

*Это то, что показывает YT при работе в заданном временном промежутке:*

[image: Это то, что показывает YT при работе в заданном временном промежутке]

*А это то, что происходит на экране после заданного промежутка:*

[image: А это то, что происходит на экране после заданного промежутка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При заданной нагрузке в 80рпс и 20 инстансов танка, один инстанс должен за 1 секунду успеть отправить и получить ответ на 4 запроса. Т.е настройки выбраны с допущением что среднее время ответа сервиса <= 250мс.
Видимо это не так, раз у танка остаются недоотправленные "по расписанию" запросы, которые он и шлет после завершения теста.

- Если не идет речи об эмуляции танком именно 20 клиентов, можно поднять число инстансов.
- Можно настроить автостоп, который принудительно будет останавливать тест после определенного времени (см. [limit](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#basic-criteria-types))